# CSS animation delay stops fade in movement

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to animate some SVG images when the page loads and found an example to build from. The example fades in objects and there is a motion to the left at the same time. This was easy to set up by duplicating the example.

Next I wanted to add a delay so the images fade in one after the other. But the delay caused the problem with objects being seen before the animation starts. I found another snippet which added `animation-fill-mode:forwards;` and `opacity: 0;` and this fixed the problem but created another. The images are now fading in on place but no movement.

How can I fix this?

The fade in movement is set up like this:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 3em;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

The full code below. When I run this code snippet here at stackoverflow it is working. But when I save it to a HTML file and open it in a browser there is no motion. Any ideas?

```css
div[class^=item] {
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 52px;
}
.item {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 3em;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 3em;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.item2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 3em;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 3em;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/231879/G.svg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/231879/A.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you testing with?  The same one you are viewing this SO page with?  Also, does this page help? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: I found the problem. I had another object animating at the end and it used the same animation name. As I said I am new to this :)

Comment: So this page is not showing a problem but rather an example how to fade in objects with movement on page load.